# Undefined reference to `wWinMain' when linking Poco::NetSSL

Tags: c++, linker-errors, poco, mingw-w64, msys2

I am linking a Poco::NetSSL component library from msys2 MinGW-w64.
There's no code actually:
*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.2 FATAL_ERROR)

project(smtp LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS NetSSL)

add_executable(send_smtp send_smtp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(send_smtp Poco::NetSSL)
```

*send_smtp.cpp*

```
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

When building I get this linker error:

```
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/send_smtp.dir/send_smtp.cpp.obj
[2/2] Linking CXX executable send_smtp.exe
FAILED: send_smtp.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/send_smtp.dir/send_smtp.cpp.obj -o send_smtp.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libsend_smtp.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libPocoNetSSL.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libPocoCrypto.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libssl.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcrypto.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libPocoUtil.dll.a  -municode  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libPocoXML.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libexpat.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libPocoJSON.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libPocoNet.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libPocoFoundation.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libpcre.dll.a  C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libz.dll.a  -liphlpapi  -liphlpapi  -lws2_32  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_w.o): in function `wmain':
C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_w.c:23: undefined reference to `wWinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

There's no error if I dont link `Poco::NetSSL`. This is very strange, since I am not using any functions from the library.
I tried explicitly setting `target_link_options(send_smtp -mconsole)`, but it didn't change anything. Neither did `-municode`.

I would understand if I used some functions from the lib which depended on the symbol (I doubt that for `wWinMain` though). But there are no invocations whatsoever...

What am I missing here? How can I use `main` as an entry point with `console` for subsytem on Windows?

---

I decided to give in and use `wWinMain` as an entry point:

```
#include <Poco/Net/SecureSMTPClientSession.h>

//int main(int, char **argv) {
int wWinMain(int, wchar_t **) {

  return 0;
}
```

But then I got a compiler error:

```
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/send_smtp.dir/send_smtp.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/send_smtp.dir/send_smtp.cpp.obj 
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -DPOCO_ENABLE_CPP11 -DPOCO_ENABLE_CPP14 -DPOCO_OS_FAMILY_WINDOWS -DPOCO_UNBUNDLED -DUNICODE -D_DEBUG -D_UNICODE  -g -municode -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/send_smtp.dir/send_smtp.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\send_smtp.dir\send_smtp.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/send_smtp.dir/send_smtp.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/sergey.kolesnik/dev/repos/DLP/smtp/send_smtp.cpp
C:/Users/sergey.kolesnik/dev/repos/DLP/smtp/send_smtp.cpp:6:5: error: conflicting declaration of C function 'int wWinMain(int, wchar_t**)'
    6 | int wWinMain(int, wchar_t **) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:70,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/UnWindows.h:30,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Platform_WIN32.h:22,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Foundation.h:100,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Net/Net.h:23,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Net/NetSSL.h:23,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Net/SecureSMTPClientSession.h:21,
                 from C:/Users/sergey.kolesnik/dev/repos/DLP/smtp/send_smtp.cpp:2:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winbase.h:1112:14: note: previous declaration 'int wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)'
 1112 |   int WINAPI wWinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd);
      |              ^~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Given the command arguments, I see that Poco passes some additional flags (I guess it was compiled with in Msys2 repo):
`-DPOCO_ENABLE_CPP11 -DPOCO_ENABLE_CPP14 -DPOCO_OS_FAMILY_WINDOWS -DPOCO_UNBUNDLED -DUNICODE`

---

Some dirty workaround would be to add a dummy cpp unit with wWinMain:

```
#include <iostream>

extern int main(int argc, char **argv);

int wWinMain(int argc, wchar_t **argv) {

  std::cout << "wWinMain:\n";

  // TODO: pass arguments
  return main(0, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: You can also try [-Wl,-subsystem,console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4441576/4074081) but it should be the default and it is indeed unclear how it got messed up by the library.

Comment: @dewaffled been there, done that.

Comment: Maybe try to build their sample apps? they provide simple [cmake](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/devel/NetSSL_OpenSSL/samples/download/CMakeLists.txt) and use [regular main](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/devel/NetSSL_OpenSSL/samples/download/src/download.cpp#L63) there. And compare compilation and linking flags if it builds successfully.

Comment: @dewaffled I think it might work, but the current problem apparantly comes from msys2 Poco build for MinGW-w64. I guess I will file a report

Answer (score 1):

Using `wmain(int, char **)` as an entry point helped to build the program without workarounds. However, it is apparently a bug within msys2 [Poco](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-poco) built package, since it forces a particular entry point upon an application.

I have opened a ticket: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/3774

Comment: Confirming this answer is indeed a solution for my Dear ImGui program with the -municode option. I changed their example code from "int main(...)" to "int wmain(...)", and the build is then be able to succeed. Before, the linker was complaining about "undefined reference to `wWinMain'". But, I'm not knowledgeable enough to say whether or not this is a msys2 bug.

Comment: @user1835157 do you link with Poco from msys2 for MinGW-w64? This answer is a workaround for that particular distribution. If not, there might be some other problem in your setup. Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/4441576/9363996 ?